# Why MVVM/WPF ComboBox SelectedItem is null in multibinding to other control's Visibility?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, multibinding

**EDIT**: I bound to same property (SearchType) that combobox binds to -> works fine. I still would like to know why my first solution described here does not work.

I have

```
public enum SearchType
{
    NetworkObjects,
    Customers
}
```

In ViewModel contructor:

```
public  SearchViewModel()
{
    SearchType = Panels.SearchType.NetworkObjects;
```

In xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <xpui:ConvertSearchTypeToVisibility x:Key="searchtypetovisibilityconverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox
            Name="SearchTypeComboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchTypes}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SearchType, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
<DataGrid.Visibility>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchtypetovisibilityconverter}">
       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Name"/>
           <Binding ElementName="SearchTypeComboBox" Path="SelectedItem" />
   </MultiBinding>
</DataGrid.Visibility>
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    string gridName = (string)values[0];
    SearchType searchType = (SearchType)values[1];
```

In Convert-method values have 2 items and values[1]==null. Also if I take away the binding SelectedItem is SearchType.NetworkObjects as set in ViewModel constructor. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is SearchTypes, and does SearchType.NetworkObjects exist in it? Also, are you getting an exception; could you use a MultiDataTrigger instead?

Comment: Does your ComboBox load with the correct items in the dropdown, and correct selected item?

Comment: it's enum. I updated the question. I don't get exception. My workaround is that binding is now bound to same property in viewmodel that combobox SelectedItem is bound (SearchType).

Comment: @Rachel . yes combobox has correct items loaded and correct item selected if i remove the binding.

Comment: I would consider that a valid approach. Now your controls depend on the view model, where if you removed the ComboBox and your DataGrid depended on it, it wouldn't compile.  Also, it may be showing up as null during control initialization process, and then be set shortly after rendering.

Comment: @NETscape: I agree. The reason for my 1st approach was that in web all multibinding examples i saw used ElementName.

Comment: @matti Could you post all of the code for your converter? I think I may have an answer but don't know what the expected behavior is

Comment: How many times it hit converter. When do you apply data context?

Comment: I do not set DataContext manually. Instead it's done by underlying platform/framework. I think the problem is that the framework sets the DataContext.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks a lot it's called too times per DataGrid. Second time values[1] is SearchType. I wrote an answer myself. I don't know if that is good way. I would like to "award" this bounty to you, but I can't.

Comment: sometimes it happens to me. I was not sure 100% it is, just my experience. But anyway, happy in helping you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in platform InitializeComponent in code behind is called before the DataContext is set by the platform I use. Therefore the Converter is called with the unbound (default) values, which in this case is null for the SelectedItem. The solution is to check the values-array and especially values[1] and return the Bindin.DoNothing if the value is null (or anything but SearchType).

Guess this is good practice in general. Thanks to @Neil and @NETScape to point this out.

```
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[0] is string && values[1] is SearchType)
        {
            string gridName = (string)values[0];
            SearchType searchType = (SearchType)values[1];

            if ((gridName == "ObjectSearchResults" && searchType == SearchType.NetworkObjects) ||
                (gridName == "CustomerSearchResults" && searchType == SearchType.Customers))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect that there is something going wrong in code that you haven't posted.  I wrote up a solution with very similar behavior using the provided code and there was no case where `values[1] == null` unless I removed the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` binding.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73c7e73fcaa96c0d6327) is the working sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using a framework/platform with a ViewModel class and the problem is probably there.

Comment: And as you said the problem was with Converter. The condition to test values should have been in the start (which was already shown in question).